# NoViableAltException: Unexpected token in @NamedQuery

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following query, which is working when I use it directly at the db:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Sentitems.findWhereSendingDateTimeIsYesterdayByStatus",
        query = "SELECT s FROM Sentitems s WHERE s.status = :status AND DATE_FORMAT(s.sendingDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)")
```

When running the application, a `NoViableAltException` is thrown:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Sentitems.findWhereSendingDateTimeIsYesterdayByStatus: SELECT s FROM Sentitems s WHERE s.status = :status AND DATE_FORMAT(s.sendingDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)], line 1, column 66: unexpected token [(].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(83@[()* loopback of 383:9: (d= DOT right= attribute )*])
```

Comment: and in which JPA documentation does it say that "DATE_FORMAT" is a valid JPQL function? And repeat the process for "SUBDATE"/ "CURDATE()" You have checked haven't you?

Comment: think you should use NamedNativeQuery isntead of NamedQuery ref:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `@NamedNativeQuery`. You seem to be using some DB specific syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Like Balaji Krishnan said in the comments, the solution is to use `@NamedNativeQuery` instead of `@NamedQuery`.